# Sitecore8 social connect does not import configured Facebook profile properties

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-social-connected, sitecore8

According to this article:
http://techmusingz.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/social-connected-with-sitecore-facebook-2-access-facebook-information/ 
I should get the properties configured in Sitecore.Social.ProfileMapping.Facebook.config imported to the SC User Profile:
[image]

All I get however are these:

```
fb_basicData_id: 100001964217563
fb_basicData_email: <hidden>@hotmail.com
fb_basicData_appKey: <hidden> 
fb_basicData_appSecret: <hidden> 
fb_basicData_accessTokenSecret: <hidden> 
fb_lastRenewed: 20150106T013821Z 
fb_fieldsLastRenewed: 20150105T234345Z
```

How do I get the other properties to populate?

Comment: I am going to take a shot in the dark with this as I have not yet had a chance to investigate the SiteCore 8 social features... Has the specified user account completed all the other fields (such as work, education, etc.) as some of these fields are optional. What are the privacy settings for the specified user account. It may have set some of the info to only be available to friends instead of everyone, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately that all checks out. The profile information is there and there should be no restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 3.0, Social Connected stores social profile fields in Sitecore xDB contact facets. This is why you don't have them in user profile.

To get the required fields, you should use Social Connected API. Particularly, you should use the GetSocialProfile method of the SocialProfileManager class to get social profile of a user in a specific network. And then you will have access to all social profile fields in the Fields property of the social profile. Example:

```
var socialProfileManager = ExecutingContext.Current.IoC.Get<ISocialProfileManager>(); // or create it directly: new SocialProfileManager();
var socialProfile = socialProfileManager.GetSocialProfile(“userName”, “Facebook”);
var facebookGender = socialProfile.Fields[“fb_gender”];
```

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using this with? I do not see ExecutingContext.Current.. are you using your own DI container?

The second method returns an empty profiles with no fields. I have checked my configuration, secutiry, etc., but still no luck.

Comment: I'm using Sitecore Experience Platform 8 - Update 2.
`ExecutingContext.Current` - it is a part of Social Connected, to use it you must reference the Sitecore.Social.Infrastructure.dll assembly.
Alternatively, you can just create an instance directly: `new SocialProfileManager()`

Comment: @Derek I would suggest you to check if there is the appropriate social profile stored in XDB. To do this, you will need to find an appropriate contact in the "Contacts" collection and check if there is a SocialProfile facet with the appropriate network element.

Comment: @VitaliiTylyk I am not getting any items in the Fields even though I used the same code. My Profile Mapping config is also updated but still no luck. Could you please suggest where I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same issue on Sitecore 8. 
Indeed the basic data from facebook is available from the `GetCustomProperty` function, but the rest of the profile data is later retrieved & made available under the *SocialProfileManager*.

**For this class to be available remember to reference the Sitecore.Social.Api.dll and Sitecore.Social.Domain.dll in your project.**

After that f.e.:

```
string facebook_email = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("fb_basicData_email");
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(facebook_email))
{
    email.Text = facebook_email; // update UI here
}
var socialProfile = new SocialProfileManager();
// Do we have an extra profile from the user?
if (socialProfile.SocialProfileExists(user.Name, "Facebook"))
{
    var facebookProfile = socialProfile.GetSocialProfile(user.Name, "Facebook");
    if (facebookProfile.Fields["fb_first_name"] != null)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```